# A guest user cannot make purchases on a WordPress site

Tags: wordpress

user guest in wordpress site cannot but and redirect to page html_block_id=8
aber this page not exist and i cannot change or edit this page to buy as user guest

How can I solve this problem?
in wocommerce page i check to user guest can buy by without login to site

Comment: Hello - Can you provide some more information in an [edit]? As it stands your question is really hard to understand and answer. If possible, provide a [mcve].